# Problematic margins and weird scroll behavior in IE

Tags: html, css

I tried to recreate the problem I'm having in my current design. First of all, here is the link:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/tohtb9gx

HTML:

```
<head><title>test</title></head>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">            
            Test what is going on?
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;   
}
#container {
    margin: 100px;
}
```

the problem is `margin`. When there is this big margin, no matter how little the content is, IE always renders the page with scroll. The page is fine in Chrome and FireFox, but even with no content, the magical mighty IE is always hungry for the mysterious scroll.

Why is this happening?

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you tell in which version of IE you are facing this Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Solution for your problem.
Give float for body.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#container {
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    Test what is going on?
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```